# How do I remove these black pixels from my baked texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-baking

How do I remove the black pixels in this Cycles baked texture?

[image]

Comment: the texture seems to be stretched. Can that be due to the image resolution compared to the plane surface ?

Comment: quite difficult to tell, since we have no information about your texture setup. But yeah, from the looks of it I agree with Vinc3r below.

Comment: It might be worth using Lightmap Pack unwrap for baking AO. It will make all the islands being oriented perpendicular pixels' distribution by splitting islands into smaller ones and thus no such things will be visible even on lower resolution.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is directly dependent of the texture size here.

There is no light under the cross, so there are blacks pixels to write on the texture. Here one pixel of the texture is a bit larger than the cross, so we can see these black pixels.

This can also appears when you're at the border of an uv island, if you don't activate the margin option in the baking panel, but it's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the size of the baked image:

[image]

[image]